# window.screen.colorDepth property for CefSharp Offscreen

Tags: cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

So, I would like to create an offscreen CefSharp scraper that would be difficult to detect with fingerprints. However, when I use it to open https://amiunique.org/fp and click "View more details", my screen resolution is displayed as "1366x768x0", which means that my browser's colorDepth property is set to zero.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSBby.png)

My guess would be that I need to either enable some kind of graphic option in the settings, or override the window.screen property with something like

```
window.screen = new function() { this.colorDepth = 24, this.pixelDepth = 24};
```

But none of that seems to work. Is there some way to fix that, or maybe some kind of workaround?

Code sample:

```
public static bool SiteReady;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Cef.Initialize();
    Task.Run(async () => await Scrape()).Wait();
    Helper.Log("Done!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static async Task Scrape()
{
    using (var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://amiunique.org/fp"))
    {
        SiteReady = false;

        // create the loading handler
        EventHandler<LoadingStateChangedEventArgs> handler = null;
        handler = async (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.IsLoading) return;
            var view = (ChromiumWebBrowser)sender;
            view.LoadingStateChanged -= handler;

            // wait for the page to load completely
            await Task.Delay(20000);

            // change the window size to fit all displayed data
            view.Size = new Size(2000, 2500);

            // click the "view more details" button and wait for the next page to load
            await view.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementById('detBut').click();");

            await Task.Delay(1000);

            while (view.IsLoading)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10);
            }

            // save the screenshot
            using (var task = await view.ScreenshotAsync())
            {
                task.Save("C:/Screens/screenshot.png");
            }

            // indicate that we are done with the page
            SiteReady = true;
        };

        browser.LoadingStateChanged += handler;

        while (SiteReady != true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
}
```